# Kendo UI Treeview Checkbox Parent Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, asp.net-mvc-5, treeview

I am quite new to kendo ui, and I have a very similar tree view as below:

```
 http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes
```

Can I know how to get parent id when the children being selected? By using above URL as example, when I checked on "about.html", how can I retrieve value "1,2,3" instead of just return me "3"?

When I choose "about.html" and "index.html", its should return me "1,2,3,4"

[14/4 - update] Sorry to make confusion earlier.
Below is the jsfiddle I have made:
http://jsfiddle.net/ntc2000/qgkzpv3d/2/

Scenario:

1. when I choose "kendo.css", it's should return "3,4,5".
2. when I choose "jquery.css", it's should return "3,4,6"
3. if I choose "Kendo UI Project", it's should return "3,4,5,6" --> currently working

Comment: What do you mean _parent id_ and  _retrieve value "1,2,3"_? Do you elements have an `id` attribute? Are you referring to the index of the item in the collection? Show some of your html and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry for confusion made, below is the example i made in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ntc2000/qgkzpv3d/2/

When I check on "kendo.css", expected result should return me "3,4,5" instead of "5".

Comment: You can use `.parents('li')` to get the containing `<li>` elements, then find the 1st checkbox in each and get its value. Not sure exactly what you want to do with the result, but I have updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qgkzpv3d/3/) with and example of what you could do.

Comment: Thank you Stephen Muecke, it's solve my issue. Appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: Since I'm not sure how you wanted to use this, I can't give an answer, so you should add your own answer with the code, and accept it to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

In checkedNodeIds you can push the parent of the checked node to the checkedNodes array.

something like this:

```
// function that gathers IDs of checked nodes
    function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].parent().parent();
            }

            if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course you should do some checks for undefined and perhaps create a variable to hold the nodes[i]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did try parent().parent() ealier but it's just return 1 level up parent on it's child. The treeview is dynamically generated by razor, it's can be multiple layer(more than 3 parents) before reaching the child.